# How do we convert NETCONF YANG file to equivalent java class file without using plugins?

Tags: java, ietf-netmod-yang

I need to convert given YANG file to JAVA class file without using plugins. How to map the YANG structures to java elements?

Answer (score 1):

We don't. You can't. Java doesn't have built-in support for [RFC 6020](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020) (yang). Further, it doesn't have built-in support for [RFC 4741](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4741) (netconf). The Wikipedia entry on [NETCONF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NETCONF) says (in part) *the first version of the base NETCONF protocol was published as RFC 4741 in December 2006*. Java is significantly older.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/tail-f-systems/JNC. "JNC (Java NETCONF Client) is the name of a Java library for communicating with NETCONF agents, and a plugin for pyang (http://code.google.com/p/pyang/) to generate Java classes from YANG models, to be used by the JNC library."